# Create proxy from existing object

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

Using Castle.DynamicProxy, what is the best way to create a proxy from an existing class instance?

```
// The actual object
Person steve = new Person() { Name = "Steve" };

// Create a proxy of the object
Person fakeSteve = _proxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget<Person>(steve, interceptor)

// fakeSteve now has steve as target, but its properties are still null...
```

Here's the Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the interceptor class:

```
public class PersonInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {   
        Person p = invocation.InvocationTarget as Person;

        if (invocation.Method.Name.Equals(get_Name)
        {
            LoadName(p);
        }
    }

    private void LoadName(Person p)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name))
        {
            p.Name = "FakeSteve";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Person class has only non-virtual properties the proxy can't access them. Try to make the properties virtual.

http://kozmic.net/2009/02/23/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-vi-handling-non-virtual-methods/

Comment: Name is a virtual property. Question updated with Person definition.

Comment: Ok, so what does your interceptor do?

Comment: The idea is to lazy load some (virtual) properties.

Comment: Ok, but what does the interceptor really do? Can you add the implementation?

Comment: Added, it's very basic as I'm just getting started with this.

Comment: First of all you should call invocation.Proceed() in your Intercept method. That could already be the solution to your problem. But you are changing the value of the target in your get Method. I'm not sure whether this is really a good idea.

Comment: That was indeed part of the problem and it seems that I need to use CreateClassProxy iso CreateClassProxyWithTarget to keep all non virtual members in sync.